# Change the values of an item after an AJAX request

Tags: jquery, json

I have tried to add an `if` statement to change the `weekday_tinyint` to `"Sunday"` if `value = 1`, but when I do this it seems to mess up the returned object.

The following code seems to work just fine. Please advise me on the best way to create an array and then process the array so I can make changes to the individual items before listing them.

Thank you.

```html
<div class="mypanel"></div>
```

```js
index = 0;
day = 0;

$.getJSON('https://arizona-na.org/bmlt/main_server/client_interface/json/?switcher=GetSearchResults&services=5', function(data) {
  while (index < data.length) {
    if (text === undefined) {
      var text = `${data[index].weekday_tinyint}` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` + `${data[index].start_time}` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` + `${data[index].meeting_name}` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` + `(` + `${data[index].formats}` + `)` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` +
        `<a target="_blank" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=` + `${data[index].latitude}` + `,` + `${data[index].longitude}` + `">` + `${data[index].location_text}` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;` + `${data[index].location_info}` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;` + `${data[index].location_street}` + `,&nbsp;&nbsp;` + `${data[index].location_municipality}` + `</a><br>`;
    } else {
      var text = text + `${data[index].weekday_tinyint}` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` + `${data[index].start_time}` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` + `${data[index].meeting_name}` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` + `(` + `${data[index].formats}` + `)` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` +
        `<a target="_blank" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=` + `${data[index].latitude}` + `,` + `${data[index].longitude}` + `">` + `${data[index].location_text}` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;` + `${data[index].location_info}` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;` + `${data[index].location_street}` + `,&nbsp;&nbsp;` + `${data[index].location_municipality}` + `</a><br>`;
    }
    index++;
  }
  $(".mypanel").html(text);
});
```

I tried changing the script to the following and received errors...

```
var index = 0;
    var daytext = "";

    $.getJSON('https://arizona-na.org/bmlt/main_server/client_interface/json/?switcher=GetSearchResults&services=5', function(data) {

     while (index < data.length) {
        if (${data[index].weekday_tinyint} === 1) 
       daytext = `Sunday`; 
       else daytext = `other day`;

      if (text === undefined) {
       var text = `$daytext` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` + `${data[index].start_time}` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` + `${data[index].meeting_name}` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` + `(` + `${data[index].formats}` + `)` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` + 
      `<a target="_blank" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=` + `${data[index].latitude}` + `,` +  `${data[index].longitude}` + `">` + `${data[index].location_text}` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;` +  `${data[index].location_info}` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;` + `${data[index].location_street}` + `,&nbsp;&nbsp;` + `${data[index].location_municipality}` + `</a><br>`;
      } else {
      var text = text + `${data[index].weekday_tinyint}` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` + `${data[index].start_time}` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` + `${data[index].meeting_name}` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` + `(` + `${data[index].formats}` + `)` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` + 
      `<a target="_blank" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=` + `${data[index].latitude}` + `,` +  `${data[index].longitude}` + `">` + `${data[index].location_text}` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;` +  `${data[index].location_info}` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;` + `${data[index].location_street}` + `,&nbsp;&nbsp;` + `${data[index].location_municipality}` + `</a><br>`;
      }
      index++;
     }
     $(".mypanel").html(text);
    });
```

Comment: Where is your `if` statement? What is the value of `data` that's returned? Also concatenating template literals seems to be missing the point of them entirely.

Comment: What are the errors? You shouldn't check for the variable `text` without initializing it first... I'm surprised that even works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all looks a bit complex what you're doing there. I would suggest to simplify the whole thing and use `.map()` function instead of your while loop, also I suggest to give your html element an ID instead of the class:

```
<div id="mypanel"></div>
```

then your script would be as follows

```
$.getJSON('https://arizona-na.org/bmlt/main_server/client_interface/json/?switcher=GetSearchResults&services=5', function(data) {
 var text = data.map(obj => {
 var strDay = "";
 switch (parseInt(obj.weekday_tinyint)){
  case 1: strDay = "Sunday"; break;
  case 2: strDay = "Monday"; break;
  case 3: strDay = "Tuesday"; break;
  case 4: strDay = "Wednesday"; break;
  case 5: strDay = "Thursday"; break;
  case 6: strDay = "Friday"; break;
  case 7: strDay = "Saturday"; break;
 }

 return `${strDay}` +`&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` + 
  `${obj.start_time}` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` + 
  `${data[index].meeting_name}` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` + 
  `(` + `${obj.formats}` + `)` + 
  `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` +
  `<a target="_blank" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=` + `${obj.latitude}` + 
  `,` + `${obj.longitude}` + `">` + `${obj.location_text}` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;` + 
  `${obj.location_info}` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;` + `${obj.location_street}` + 
  `,&nbsp;&nbsp;` + `${obj.location_municipality}` + `</a><br>`;
 });
 $("#mypanel").html(text);
});
```

Here is the documentation for the JavaScript `map()` function
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp

And here is the functioning [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y0u82bzc/4/)

Comment: Thank you for creating more concise code, however I am still looking for a way to display the weekday e.g., "Sunday", "Monday", etc. instead of the numeric value for {weekday_tinyint}.

Comment: Edwin,

Thanks again for the quick reply, but the JsFiddle does not include the new code and when I replaced what was there with the additional code it produces nothing.